# Newly created PyDev Project not showing up in Eclipse Neon PyDevPackage Explorer

Tags: pydev, eclipse-neon

I just installed Eclipse Neon.  I also have Eclipse Mars still lying around on my system.  When I opened Neon it asked if I wanted to convert my workspace and I did.

So I installed PyDev through `Help/Install` on Neon and now I go to `File/New/PyDev Project` and follow the prompts to create a new Python project.  It does not show up in PyDev Package Explorer.  If I try to create it again with the same name, it says I cannot because the project already exists.

When I first installed PyDev, 3 projects showed up in the PyDev Package Explorer, but they all contain folders underneath which cannot be expanded so I don't think those 3 projects are being handled correctly either.  Actually they are closed projects I see, but I see at least 1 is a Java project, so it does not belong to that perspective.

So any idea why Neon/PyDev is not handling my Python projects correctly?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to work a little better anyway in the Package Explorer in the Java perspective.  Still would like to know about the PyDev perspective though.

Comment: There's a FAQ for that: http://pydev.sourceforge.net/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhynothingshowsinthePyDevPackageExplorer%3F -- can you see if one of those fixes it for you?

Comment: @Fabio Zadrozny Working sets was selected in top level elements by default it appears.  If I change to projects, I get all projects both Java and Python.  Is this what I should expect?  Is there a way to show only the Python projects.  I can't find anything under customize view, for instance, to accomplish this.

Comment: In the customize view, you can check: PyDev: non-PyDev Projects to filter out non-PyDev projects (i.e.: show only PyDev projects).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking reverse logic when I saw that, that is checking it would include non-Pydev projects.  That combination of filter out non python and selecting projects instead of working set does it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the above comments, there were two defaults for PyDev Package Explorer I was not expecting when I installed Neon (which may well not just apply to Neon, but other versions as well)

1. Display working sets was the default behaviour  and I wanted display projects.
2. I wanted non-Pydev projects filtered out and they were not